# Taylor Expansion for the Return averaged over k periods?

Tags: taylor-expansion, finance, economics

this is my first question here. I need help to understand the Taylor Expansion which gives the (2.2.5) equation (see the pictures). Thanks
(pictures from: Schmidt - Quantitative Finance for Physicists. An Introduction. 2005)

[definition simple return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/657QH.jpg)

[taylor expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gj2Yq.jpg)

Comment: It is not obvious to me how Taylor expansion was used at all! Is the expansion taken for a function R(t,k) for two variables? What is the point used for the expansion? Is it (0,0)? Even for a single variable, it would look very complex. The ebook is here: https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=bCpd1_KziPYC&pg=PA8&dq=small+returns+period+taylor+series+t,k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA-9L8paD8AhU2QaQEHYhyDx8Q6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=small%20returns%20period%20taylor%20series%20t%2Ck&f=false

Comment: Yeah...So am I!

Comment: If this appears in page 7 of the book...Maybe one could look for a simpler text!

Comment: Hi Ged, could you type your question fully in here instead of referring to screenshots? It would help others to be able to find your question and make your question more accessible to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the book refers to in fact is the Taylor expansion of the $\log(1+x)$ function about $x_0=0$, that is $\log(1+x) = x + o(x)$, where $o(x)$ is  [the error term](https://math.fandom.com/wiki/Little-o_notation).

The equation (2.2.4) can be rearranged into
$$
 1+ \tilde R(t,k) = \left[\Pi_{i=0}^{k-1} \big(1+R(t-i)\big)\right]^{1/k}.
$$
Taking logarithm,
$$
  \log \big(1+\tilde R(t,k) \big) = \frac 1 k \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \log \big(1+R(t-i)\big),
$$
$$
  \tilde R(t,k) + o(\tilde R(t,k)) = \frac 1 k \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \big(R(t-i) + o(R(t-i))\big).
$$
When the interest rates are small, the error terms can be neglected and the approximate formule (2.2.5) is obtained:
$$
  \tilde R(t,k) \approx \frac 1 k \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} R(t-i).
$$